# Google Cloud Vision API returning nothting for Type = TEXT_DETECTION

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm working on an OCR android application using Google Cloud Vision API

For testing I've used the sample application which is provided by Google

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/android/CloudVision

I've tested it for type "LABEL_DETECTION" and it works fine

I've updated this sample application to work for type "TEXT_DETECTION" instead of "LABEL_DETECTION"

I've tested it using this image and it return "nothing" result

[ocr_image]

[image]

Appreciate if anyone knows what is the issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it happened because I forgot to change convertResponsetoString method.

try to change this:

List labels = response.getResponses().get(0).**getLabelAnnotations**();

to this:

List labels = response.getResponses().get(0).**getTextAnnotations**();